# How to generate a DFA that recognizes a non-regular Grammar

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, formal-grammars

How would you convert the following grammar to a DFA that recognizes its language?
\begin{align}
&G = (\{S,A,B\},\{0,1\}, S, P)\\
&P\colon  
&&S\rightarrow A1B\\
&&&A \rightarrow0A|\epsilon \\
&&&B \rightarrow0B|1B|\epsilon 
\end{align}

And this is the DFA that recognizes $L(G)$:

[image: DFA]

But I don't really know how to generate that DFA; to me, it makes sense that both $A$ and $B$ were accepting states, and I (wrongfully) generated mine like this:

My NFA

[image]

And its DFA conversion

[image]

1. How is the correct one generated?
2. Why isn't $A$ an accepting state?
3. What happens to $S$ as a state?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your procedure. Your Qs: 1) through state minimisation. 2. $q_1$ encompasses both $A$ and $B$, so $A$ (to the extent that it still exists in the DFA) is still accepting. 3) state names don't matter. The start state is labeled $q_0$ but calling it $S$ would change nothing.

Comment: `There's nothing wrong with your procedure` not sure about that: the grammar pretty much generates any string of 0 and 1 containing at least one 1, every automaton following `But` requires starting with 1.

Comment: @greybeard Yeah, i figured the Language it generates, but my doubt is about the way to proceed with the solution, since its not a regular grammar, but it does generate a regular language, should i just create an AFD that accepts that language? (i mean, without any algorithm or equivalence as i would do with a regular grammar) just by "observation"?